# Angular Write a conditional directive to a tag

Tags: angular, directive

I want to add a directive to a tag like

```
<div class="test" directive></div>
```

I tired to use the ternary operator to write condition, if the condition is true then I want to show or else empty

```
<div class="test" {{(checkName==true?'directive':'')}}></div>
```

Comment: try `[attr-directive]="checkName"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add/remove directives to an element or component dynamically.

Directives are only added to selectors that are added to a components template statically.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6970

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "work". You can add an attribute using `[attr.my-attr]="true"`, but that will never result in a directive to be added, only the attribute in the DOM.